# Diferencia entre usar var y let dentro de bloques

Tags: javascript, variables, variables-globales

¿Cuál es la diferencia entre el ámbito de variables declaradas con let y var en un bloque de código como funciones, condiciones if else, ciclos for, while, y cómo puede afectar esto al comportamiento del programa?

Otra duda, si declaro una variable ya sea con let o var con un valor y luego cambio el valor cuando reasigne la variable, funciona igual en ambos ámbitos y por bloques?

por ejemplo así:

```
let name = "jose";
name = "manuel";
```

```
var name = "alfredo";
name = "manuel";
```

Yo sé que con var si funciona pero con let no siempre, no estoy seguro si sea por bloques que las hace en un ámbito local

Es mi duda que tengo al respecto con var y let

Comment: Ya hay mucha información de eso https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let

Comment: `var` es global, `let` es solo para un bloque de código, si `let` está dentro de una condición solamente se podrá usar ahí. Si se usan antes de ser declaradas, `var` es `undefined` y `let` un `ReferenceError`